# How to make sure only one h:selectOneRadio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I have some javascript code (that I borrowed from BalusC) that is used to make sure only one h:selectOneRadio button is selected in a table. Unfortunately I'm getting an malformed expression error from my glassfish server:

```
Error Parsing /ClientSearch.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 13] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

Note:

```
 if (elements[i].name.substring(elements[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
```

seems to be the line with the problems

I also don't fully understand the javascript (I'm a newbie at it) and I'm hoping someone could explain it to me.

Here is the full javascript:

```
 function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
    var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
    var elements = radio.form.elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].name.substring(elements[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
            elements[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
    radio.checked = true;
}
 </script>
```

Why am I getting the error? 
And, the script itself seems wrong. Shouldn't the code be if NOT equal to id then false (as below).

```
 if (elements[i].name.substring(elements[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) != id) {
    elements[i].checked = false;
 }
```

Obviously I don't understand.

And here is the facelets code for the table:
        
            
                Clients

```
        <h:column headerText="First Name"  >
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="First Name" /></f:facet>
            #{client.firstName}
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Last Name"  >
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Last Name" /></f:facet>
            #{client.lastName}
        </h:column>

        <h:column headerText="Select"  >
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Last Name" /></f:facet>
            <h:selectOneRadio valueChangeListener="#{clientSearchBean.setSelectedItem}" >
                <f:selectItem itemValue="null" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </h:column>

        <h:column headerText="Address"  >
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Address" /></f:facet>
            #{client.address}
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Cell"  >
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Cell" /></f:facet>
            #{client.cell}
        </h:column>
        <h:column headerText="Phone"  >
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Phone" /></f:facet>
            #{client.phone}
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried (and I'm using) the BalusC code in a `<h:dataTable>` and works neat. You have two problems:

1. You're not using the JavaScript function at all (or that looks in your code):

   ```
   <h:column headerText="Select">
       <f:facet name="header">
           <h:outputText value="Last Name" />
       </f:facet>
       <!-- you forgot to add the onclick -->
       <h:selectOneRadio valueChangeListener="#{clientSearchBean.setSelectedItem}"
           onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);">
           <f:selectItem itemValue="null" />
       </h:selectOneRadio>
   </h:column>
   ```
2. Your JavaScript code has the `<` symbol. Facelets is very strict with this symbol usage. To make it work, you should use the [XML CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) usage in [Script and Style elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   //the CDATA must be used with JavaScript comments
   //<![CDATA[
       function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
           var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
           var elements = radio.form.elements;
           for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
               if (elements[i].name.substring(elements[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
                   elements[i].checked = false;
               }
           }
           radio.checked = true;
       }
   //]]>
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thanks Luiggi, your CDATA suggestion got rid of the error message. And, yes, I forgot to include the onclick event in the posted code. I had it earlier but in fiddling I dropped it somewhere. But now the javascript function won't execute (I put the onclick event back). The page doesn't seem to know that its there. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dave doesn't the JavaScript method execute or it executes but throws an unhandled exception? Do a further investigation on your problem, I could give you better guidance if you post the HTML generated page.

Comment: Got it to work by copying the global.js file (which has the function) into my .xhtml this way-      <h:outputScript library="js" name="global.js" /> But when I simply put the function into the .xhtml file and declare it as a script it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dave I've updated my question, edit the CDATA part with Javascript `//` characters and try again.

Comment: Okay, that's it. Next up, getting an in-depth knowledge of javascript.